# Saving and retrieving attachments to a shared Access db, attachment not found for other users

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access, dao

I have an Excel macro that CRUDs work orders to which the user also attaches an image. Everything gets saved to an Access db on a SharePoint folder.

For example, a work order for department A gets created, and to the record we attach a picture to an attachment field in an Access table. Department A receives the work order through the Access database which has been shared through SharePoint.

All users use the same workbook, macros, code, etc.

After a record has been updated with an image, it is displayed with the following:

```vb
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, rsP As Variant, strFile As String
Dim rsStat As DAO.Recordset

Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(db_path.Value, False, False, "MS Access;PWD=" & p.Value)

Set rsStat = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT STATUS FROM womhst WHERE wo_no = " & wo_no)

If rsStat.Fields(0).Value = "Closed" Then
    btnAddPic.Enabled = False
Else
    If Not user_role.Value = 4 Then
        btnAddPic.Enabled = False
    Else
        btnAddPic.Enabled = True
    End If
End If

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT vio_image FROM womhst WHERE wo_no = " & wo_no)
Set rsP = rs.Fields("vio_image").Value

If rsP.RecordCount = 1 Then iAtt.Picture = LoadPicture(rsP.Fields(2).Value)
```

If I run this from my machine, the image is displayed in the Image control.

However, when I run the macro from another user's machine, connecting to the Access db shared through a SharePoint folder, I get a "File not found" error when I try to display the image.

I know the following:

1. Access has updated in the second user's machine. If I open the encrypted db in that user's machine, I can see that the field has all images as it should.
2. There are other fields on the table, which the macro is reading as well. All of these read fine. If I make an update to the table in one machine, the changes are reflected, and the macro reads them (only with the files in the attachment field there is a problem)
3. Access is saving the images to a cache for each machine

After I try to view the image from the second user's machine (and get the error), I go back to my machine. At this point, I also start getting the "File not found" error.

I believe this has something to do with the cache path.

The code for updating images to Access:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim attachFld As DAO.Recordset

Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(db_path.Value, False, False, "MS Access;PWD=" & p.Value)

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM womhst WHERE wo_no = " & wo_no & ";", dbOpenDynaset)
    
rst.FindFirst "wo_no = " & wo_no
If Not rst.NoMatch Then

    rst.Edit
    
        Set attachFld = rst.Fields("vio_image").Value
        
        'If record alrady has an image, delete such that there always only one file saved
        If attachFld.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            attachFld.Delete
        End If
        
        attachFld.AddNew
        
            'user can get the file with the file dialog
            Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
            Dim fileSelected As String
            Dim myFile As Object
            
            Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
            With myFile
            .Title = "Choose File"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            fileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
            End With

            attachFld.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile fileSelected
            
        attachFld.Update
        
    rst.Update

End If

rst.Close
db.Close
ws.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround:

As I attempt to open a photo from the Access database, I save it to a temp folder. After the user views the photo, VBA deletes the temp directory:

```
Option Explicit
Dim imgDir As String

Private Sub btnExit_Click()

    DeleteTemp
    Unload Me
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    LoadImage

End Sub


Private Sub LoadImage()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim ws As DAO.Workspace

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim attachFld As DAO.Recordset

    Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(db_path.Value, False, False, "MS Access;PWD=" & p.Value)

    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM womhst WHERE wo_no = " & wo_no & ";", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    Set attachFld = rst.Fields("vio_image").Value

    Dim wd As String
    wd = ThisWorkbook.path
    imgDir = wd & "\temp3"
    
    MkDir imgDir
    
    attachFld.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile imgDir
    
    iAtt.Picture = LoadPicture(imgDir & "\" & attachFld.Fields(2))
    
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteTemp()

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
    FSO.DeleteFolder imgDir, False

End Sub
```